# Search text files, display hyperlink and print content

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am a newbie and learning to code HTML, JS and PHP. My task is create a small code to search multiple .txt files and display the matched results by hyperlink. Once the hyperlink is clicked, I display selected contents of the file.

---

```
DATAHEADER
FILE NAME
VALUES
```

---

```
Result to be displayed for Search "FILE" via hyperlinks
FILE
DIFF FILE
BLOCK BLOCK FILE
```

---

```
If any of the above hyperlinks are clicked, it's content is displayed
DATAHEADER
FILE
```

Comment: What you have tried so far

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I have tried to create pseudo code. But unable to establish starting point of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should start with [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and even with the example provided in it

So you will be having

```
<?php
$dir    = 'c:';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$files2 = scandir($dir, 1);
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
$target = '/'; 
$weeds = array('.', '..'); 
$directories = array_diff(scandir($target), $weeds); 

foreach($directories as $value) 
{ 
   if(is_dir($target.$value)) 
   { 
      echo $value.'<br />'; 
   } 
}
```

Now `$files1` and `$files2` will have the list of files as array in your specified directory in the `$dir` then you should match it with the text entered from the front end and result with appropriate result which matches with the list of files that is in your directory

### Update :

**As the user wants to do this in the client**

As the client side can't able to read the files in the server

```
.ajax({
  url: "YOUR FOLDER",
  success: function(data){
     $(data).find("a:contains(.txt)").each(function(){
        // will loop through 
        var match= $(this).attr("href");
        $('<p></p>').html(match).appendTo('a div of your choice')

     });
  }
});
```

Comment: I cannot use PHP to search within files. It has to be accomplished via HTML & JS. PHP can only be used to print the results of the selected hyperlink.

Comment: client side can't read the files that is in the server,, so let me give you an alternate solution

Comment: Where you should give the folder path in the url and you shall do it the update i have made

Comment: So the above code can be embedded within the HTML body? Do I need to have dependencies for AJAX?.

Comment: You should use the above code inside your `<script>thecode</script>` and use the `jquery.min.js` for its execution

Comment: Sulthan as much as i appreciate your inputs, is it possible this code can get any simpler. Because while I am trying to learn, i would be over-boarding myself with extra knowledge.

Comment: Ok, let me update my answer with good definition with consideration of beginner :)